# How to run other lines while another long running python script is running?

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess

I am working on a script which runs another very long running script on cmd. However, I also want to run other lines while the child process is running.

Here is my code:

```
from subprocess import Popen

p = Popen("python script.py")

print("Other stuff")
```

The thing is without the script.py is done I can't get the printed text.
How can I solve this?

Comment: have you tried printing the other stuff before starting the process?

Comment: The print other stuff is a placeholder for other computations they would like to do while the other longer process is running

Comment: SyntaxVoid is right I will do other things while the child script is running.

Comment: If you search on the phrase "Python multi-processing", you’ll find resources that can explain it much better than we can in an answer here.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you are looking for [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/multiprocessing.html) module. The way how you will start processes and what they will do - is on yours side while the module will give you an ability to run multiple processes and gather results of each process execution along with output if any.

Below is a quick implementation of the first way mentioned in the official module documentation just to show how this works:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
from subprocess import check_call

commands = [
    'echo {time}; sleep {time}; echo {time}'.format(time=5),
    'echo {time}; sleep {time}; echo {time}'.format(time=10),
    'echo {time}; sleep {time}; echo {time}'.format(time=4),
]


def sample(command):
    check_call(command, shell=True)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    with Pool(len(commands)) as p:
        p.map(sample, commands)
```